# clientid is not found in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

am getting error like this:

`'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'` does not contain a definition for `'ClentID'` and no extension method `'ClentID'` accepting a first argument of type `'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

this is my code

```
 if (document.getElementById("<%=txt_stuname.ClientID %>").value == "") {
        alert("Student Name cannot be blank");
        document.getElementById("<%=txt_stuname.ClentID %>").focus();
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Change `ClentID` to `ClientID`

```
if (document.getElementById("<%=txt_stuname.ClientID %>").value == "") {
   alert("Student Name cannot be blank");
   document.getElementById("<%=txt_stuname.ClientID %>").focus();
   return false;
}
```